# Can't write to disk

Tags: disk

I have seen questions similar to this, but the answers are either beyond me or the situation doesn't quite match mine. Would appreciate some direction.

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The OS is on a disk formatted as ext4. I added another disk to the system and formatted it as W95 FAT 32 (LBA) (0x0c). I did this because I am moving from Windows to Linux, will be needing to go back and forth with data for a while, and might need to move the disk to a Windows machine. There may have been a better format to use, but if so I didn't know any better.

I was able to transfer data from an external drive to this FAT32 drive with no problem. Now, though, when I try to create a new folder or write a file to the disk I get a message that the disk is read-only.

If I go to the properties, permissions for the disk, for Folder Access it says 'create and delete files'. If I try to change File Access underneath to 'read and write', either nothing happens or I get a message it can't be done.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What is the specific message saying it can't be done? Can you try using the terminal to `chmod 0744` it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use ntfs than fat32 on modern linux distros.

I suspect your user isn't part of the fuse group, and it's getting automounted by fuse or similar.

*sometimes this type of error happens when you try to use non-default auto-login stuff like using the nopasswdlogin group*

Comment: The business about the fuse group is, right now, over my head. How would I fix this? You may be onto something with auto-login. That is something that has changed since I was able to write to the disk. I prefer to not have to enter a password to logon. I had changed this so I didn't need to. I just went and changed it back to require a password, and now the disk in question does not show up at all in the file system. ???

Comment: OK - I figured out to go into file system and check and disk was now unmounted, so I mounted it and it shows up again. I think I can write to it now. Will be back again if I can't. I'll google fuse group and see if I can figure out what that is.

Comment: Yep - I can write to it now. Thanks a lot! It was the auto-login. Now I'm wondering if I can set it up to not logon and be able to write, but I'll enter that as a new question on another day.

Comment: It is not autologin. Because in my system i have no auto login, but i have similar issue. Can someone also review this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/358480/ubuntu-does-not-allow-to-write-in-disk-in-the-middle-of-work-after-restart-i