# Ubuntu - does not allow to write in disk, in the middle of work, after restart it does the same unless its rebooted and used F

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, kernel, filesystem, crash

Everyday my laptop in the middle of work, stop to save any files to the disk, and then nothing works

When i do reboot, it stays in the boot screen with following screen shot, unless i physically press F or other options

How do i resolve this issue permanently to not happen in the middle of work?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filesystem is corrupted; backup your data immediately. When your system becomes like the one in the first screenshot; press F to fix the partition. But I'd backup my data first before doing that.

If it persists, you can start Ubuntu from a Live CD/USB and open a partition manager and right-click your installed Ubuntu partition and select the check option.

Comment: Whats the fix???? please.

Comment: I used F to fix it but its again and again happening so daily i have a loop of this F thing. How to permanently resolve it? Cause daily minimum 5 to 10 times happening in the middle of coding/programming changes for work.

Comment: Check with SMART if your disk is failing. Then the only fix is to replace it.